# VSO WorkItem API Queries Not returning Results

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've had a powershell script working for a while now which reads and creates tasks in VSO, however it has stopped working a day or so ago. Overall the purpose was to create work items, and as part of that, I'd fetch existing items to be sure I wasn't creating duplicates.

A snippet of what is being used to fetch items is below - this has been working for months.

```
#Get current work items.
$workitemsUrl = "https://" + $instance + "/DefaultCollection/" + $project + "/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0"

#Create object to convert to JSON.
$query = @{
    query = "SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title] from workitems where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] = 1 and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity] = 'Merge' order by System.ID asc"
    }

#convert to JSON object.
$jsonQuery = ConvertTo-Json $query

$workitems = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $workitemsUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Headers @{ Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $b64token} -Body $jsonQuery
```

The response I get is valid, however it now  has no results, even though the VSO instance has plenty of tasks matching the criteria. Sample response below for what its worth:

```
@{queryType=flat; queryResultType=workItem; asOf=2018-04-11T12:15:06.073Z; columns=System.Object[]; sortColumns=System.Object[]; workItems=System.Object[]}
```

I've tried:

1. Change API version on the end of the query.
2. Change query to be very basic (Select ID from WorkItems).
3. Regenerate PAT.
4. Print out the JSON being sent to the endpoint - it matches the documentation.

Worth mentioning the script for creating tasks works fine still, and used the same PAT.

Am I missing something? If anyone can suggest solutions or troubleshooting steps it would be much appreciated.

EDIT #1
Updating with information as requested. Used same query as above, screenshot linked. Also included full code snippet of TesttaskFetch.ps1 which is a cut down version of the full script.

[No Tasks Returned Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbvH9.png)
The query used was the same as above with the same code.

EDIT #2
I found the issue - the  query was not the problem all along. It was a logical flaw in another part of my script not related to any kind of API issue. I'll close this off.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to get work items, so you know your query is correct, and the JSON payload, and it sounds like the PAT token should still be correct.  You're getting a 200 response back, so your authorization header is valid as well.  For me, I had to make sure to convert spaces in the project name to `%20`, but that's likely not your issue.  The one thing different for me is that, in the response, if I get back a collection of work items, it's a large PSCustomObject with each item, and not an `Object[]`.

Comment: How do you check the result ($workitems)? Try to create a new query with these conditions, then run the query and provide the screenshot here.

Comment: For my purposes I'm getting the count of objects (which is now always null) and was printing that to logs. I notice the issue because I no longer saw a message "found xxxx tasks in VSO". To get the output in my original post all I did was write-host $workitems. I'll get a screenshot sometime today and post it up. Thanks so far guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - the query was not the problem all along. It was a logical flaw in another part of my script not related to any kind of API issue. Thanks for the responses all, false alarm.